# Issues pulling change log using python

Tags: jira-rest-api, python-jira

I am trying to query and pull changelog details using python.

The below code returns the list of issues in the project.

```
issued = jira.search_issues('project=  proj_a', maxResults=5)

for issue in issued:
    print(issue)
```

I am trying to pass values obtained in the issue above

```
issues = jira.issue(issue,expand='changelog')
changelog = issues.changelog
projects = jira.project(project)
```

I get the below error on trying the above:

```
JIRAError: JiraError HTTP 404 url: https://abc.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/issue?expand=changelog
text: Issue does not exist or you do not have permission to see it.
```

Could anyone advise as to where am I going wrong or what permissions do I need.

Please note, if I pass a specific `issue_id` in the above code it works just fine but I am trying to pass a list of `issue_id`

Answer (score 18):

You can already receive all the changelog data in the `search_issues()` method so you don't have to get the changelog by iterating over each issue and making another API call for each issue. Check out the code below for examples on how to work with the changelog.

```py
issues = jira.search_issues('project=  proj_a', maxResults=5, expand='changelog')
for issue in issues:
    print(f"Changes from issue: {issue.key} {issue.fields.summary}")
    print(f"Number of Changelog entries found: {issue.changelog.total}") # number of changelog entries (careful, each entry can have multiple field changes)

    for history in issue.changelog.histories:
        print(f"Author: {history.author}") # person who did the change
        print(f"Timestamp: {history.created}") # when did the change happen?
        print("\nListing all items that changed:")

        for item in history.items:
            print(f"Field name: {item.field}") # field to which the change happened
            print(f"Changed to: {item.toString}") # new value, item.to might be better in some cases depending on your needs.
            print(f"Changed from: {item.fromString}") # old value, item.from might be better in some cases depending on your needs.
            print()
    print()
```

Just to explain what you did wrong before when iterating over each issue: you have to use the `issue.key`, not the `issue-resource` itself. When you simply pass the `issue`, it won't be handled correctly as a parameter in jira.issue(). Instead, pass `issue.key`:

```
for issue in issues:
    print(issue.key)
    myIssue = jira.issue(issue.key, expand='changelog')
```