# How to get changelog with python from jira and how to get the sprint data?

Tags: python, jira-rest-api, changelog, sprint

I need to get the changelog data from Jira. In postman, this link works: https://xxxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=xx&expand=changelog

But I need to get it done in Python. I tried to specify it in the jira.instance.jql() part by adding expand = changelog OR expand = changelog.histories but it did not work.

```
results = jira_instance.jql("project = xx", limit = 100, expand = changelong, fields=["issuetype", "status", "summary"])


df = pd.json_normalize(results["issues"])

FIELDS_OF_INTEREST = ["key", "fields.summary", "fields.issuetype.name", "fields.status.name", "fields.status.statusCategory.name"]
```

Anyone has any experience with this?

About the sprint column: I know the board id but it seems it is not possible to use it in jql search?

Thank you!

Comment: maybe you have the same Problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56692222/issues-pulling-change-log-using-python

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need expand="changelog" in the API call.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Atlassian module to execute your query:

```
from atlassian import Jira

class JiraManager:

    def __init__(self, jiraToken, strUserName):
        self.jiraToken = jiraToken
        self.strUserName = strUserName

    def auth(self):
        jira = Jira(url='https://{YOUR ATLASSIAN URL HERE}', username=self.strUserName, password=self.jiraToken, cloud=True)
        return jira

    def getProject(self, strProject, strType, dtCreated):

        jira = self.auth()
        jql_request = f'project = {strProject} AND type = {strType} AND created >= {dtCreated} AND status NOT IN (Closed, Resolved) ORDER BY issuekey'
        dictResponse = jira.jql(jql_request, expand="changelog")
        return dictResponse["issues"]
```

these are the keys returned:

```
dict_keys(['expand', 'id', 'self', 'key', 'changelog', 'fields'])
```

You can use it like so:

```
jm = jiraManager.JiraManager(jiraToken, "YOUR USERNAME")

def filterEpicData(lstEpics): 

    dictEpics = {}

    for thisEpic in lstEpics: 
        print(thisEpic["changelog"]["histories"][0]["items"])
        break

lstEpics = jm.getProject("KME", "epic", "2023-01-01")
filterEpicData(lstEpics)
```

the output will be something like this:

```
[{'field': 'labels', 'fieldtype': 'jira', 'fieldId': 'labels', 'from': None, 'fromString': '', 'to': None, 'toString': 'Q1_2023_candidate'}]
```